# if php page loaded into div, show or hide HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, if-statement, paypal

I've basically got a checkout page **(index.php)** in which I load **4 other pages** into the **"content div"** (when the link is pressed)

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

using..

```
 $("#content").load(link + '.php');
```

The problem is im using two different paypal checkout forms (standard and recurring) on the same page **(index.php)** which both have conflicting ID's which I cannot change.

So it looks like..

```
<form id="checkout_form" name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr" id="form" method="post" >
        <input type="hidden" id="unique" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />

</form>
```

and the second one..

```
<form id="checkout_form2" name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr" id="form" method="post" >
            <input type="hidden" id="unique" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />

    </form>
```

I'd like to basicaly write a function that says.. **IF page ID inside content div** 
**=xyz** then use/show form1 
else if **page=zzz** use/show form2

..the issue is basically causing empty fields to sometimes be sent through to the paypal IPN

Comment: what do you mean you can't change them? ID's are unique; use a class. Plus, both your forms have 2x ID's each, why the "multiple personalities"?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I cannot change them as they are specific ID's defined by paypal in order to pass through data... One form is for recurring billing another is for normal billing.. Im using a one-page ajax solution.

Comment: you've been given answers below. I honestly can't see why you're constraint to not changing the IDs. Where does that code come from anyway?

Comment: @Fred-ii- - Take a look at the live link http://derrick.dk/insta2/

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've tried the awnsers below but they don't work I think it may need a php solution

Comment: It would be nice on your part if you were to let those people know. As it stands, they have no idea if their code works for you or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your check has to be done after the `load()` completes like this

```
$("#content").load(link + '.php', function() {
   // Do your id check here
   if($("#xyz").length) {
      $("#form1").show();
      $("#form2").hide();
   }
   else {
       $("#form1").hide();
       $("#form2").show();
   }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for attempt but didn't understand the do ID check here?

Comment: You need to replace `xyz` with the actual ID which you want to check.

Comment: Sorry I meant I did do that but it only ever shows one condition

Comment: @yella-dom Can you provide the html contents send from php

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#content").children("#xyz")) {  //if #xyz exists in #content
    $("#form1").show();                //show form 1
}
else {                                 //otherwise
    $("#form2").show();                //show form 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery realization after load content:

```
if($('#content').find('#xyz').length)
{
     $('#checkout_form').show(); // .hide();
}else if($('#content').find('#zzz').length)
{
     $('#checkout_form2').show(); // .hide();
}else
{
     $('#checkout_form3').show(); // .hide();
}
```

or native JS `show()/hide() is form.style.display == 'none' // 'block'`